# Diseño de un display en Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy utilizando *C#* y *windows forms* para poder representar un `display` en pantalla, lo que quiero hacer es:

Tengo 7 `labels`, que van a hacer de `display` y 11 botones (0, 1, 2, 3,....., 9, Off) que al pulsar alguno de estos botones me tiene que salir el número correspondiente en el `display`, por ejemplo, si pulso 0, me tiene que salir 0 en el `display` y así hasta nueve y en el último caso que es Off, no mostrar nada.

Tengo otros dos botones pero no tiene nada que ver con esto.

Todo esto que he comentado me sale bien, pero ahora otra cosa que quiero implementar al programa es que al pulsar la tecla del teclado por ejemplo el '1' o otro cualquier número me lo lea y me lo muestre por pantalla (el display me refiero), pero no consigo esto último.

Este es mi código

```
namespace Casa
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = false;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = false;
            label7.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
            timer2.Interval = 1000;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            timer3.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = false;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer3.Interval = 1000;
            timer3.Enabled = false;
            timer4.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer4.Interval = 1000;
            timer4.Enabled = false;
            timer5.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer5_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
            timer5.Interval = 1000;
            timer5.Enabled = false;
            timer6.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer6_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer6.Interval = 1000;
            timer6.Enabled = false;
            timer7.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer7_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer7.Interval = 1000;
            timer7.Enabled = false;
            timer8.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer8_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
            timer8.Interval = 1000;
            timer8.Enabled = false;
            timer9.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer9_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer9.Interval = 1000;
            timer9.Enabled = false;
            timer10.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer10_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            timer10.Interval = 1000;
            timer10.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        /// Estos dos métodos de abajo son de prueba de lo que quiero probar, que al pulsar la 
        /// tecla, el '0' por ejemplo me salga en el display representado, tendría que tener los mismos
        /// valores que el del botón: button1_Click.
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar=='a')
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label2.Visible = true;
                label3.Visible = false;
                label4.Visible = true;
                label5.Visible = true;
                label6.Visible = true;
                label7.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu imagen ya no es accesible, en lugar de dejarla en un servidor externo la puedes adjuntarla directamente en la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Por defecto cuando pulsas una tecla se genera el evento de teclado del control que tiene el foco. El del formulario únicamente salta si no hay ningún control activo.

Para capturar los eventos de teclado a nivel de formulario debes establecer la propiedad KeyPreview a true.

Además tal y como lo estás haciendo repites mucho código, y más que tendrás que repetir para hacer la entrada de teclado. Te recomendaría refactorizar el código para tener un único método que muestre los caracteres en el display.

Las diferentes visualizaciones las podrías tener en un Dictionary en el que la clave sea el carácter a mostrar y el valor los segmentos del display a activar.

Podrías también definir el carácter a mostrar por cada botón en la propiedad Tag de forma que pudieses utilizar un único controlador del evento click para todos los botones.

Échale un vistazo a este ejemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Display> _displays;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _displays = new Dictionary<string, Display>();
        _displays.Add("off", new Display());
        _displays.Add("0",
            new Display { Top = true, TopLeft = true, TopRight = true, BottomLeft = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true });
        _displays.Add("1", new Display {TopRight = true, BottomRight = true});
        _displays.Add("2",
            new Display() {Top = true, TopRight = true, Middle = true, BottomLeft = true, Bottom = true});
        _displays.Add("3",
            new Display {Top = true, TopRight = true, Middle = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true});
        _displays.Add("4", new Display {TopLeft = true, TopRight = true, Middle = true, BottomRight = true});
        _displays.Add("5",
            new Display {Top = true, TopLeft = true, Middle = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true});
        _displays.Add("6",
            new Display { Top = true, TopLeft = true, Middle = true, BottomLeft = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true});
        _displays.Add("7", 
            new Display { Top = true, TopRight = true, BottomRight = true});
        _displays.Add("8", 
            new Display { Top=true, TopLeft = true, TopRight = true, Middle = true, BottomLeft = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true});
        _displays.Add("9",
            new Display { Top = true, TopLeft = true, TopRight = true, Middle = true, BottomRight = true, Bottom = true});
        Button[] buttons =
        {
            button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9,
            button10, button11
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].Tag = i < 10 ? i.ToString() : "off";
            buttons[i].Click += Button_Click;
        }
        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyPress += Form_KeyPress;
    }

    private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show((string)((Control)sender).Tag);
    }

    private void Show(string key)
    {
        if (!_displays.ContainsKey(key)) return;

        Display display = _displays[key];
        label1.Visible = display.Top;
        label2.Visible = display.TopLeft;
        label3.Visible = display.Middle;
        label4.Visible = display.TopRight;
        label5.Visible = display.BottomLeft;
        label6.Visible = display.BottomRight;
        label7.Visible = display.Bottom;
    }

}

internal class Display
{
    public bool Top;
    public bool TopLeft;
    public bool TopRight;
    public bool Middle;
    public bool BottomLeft;
    public bool BottomRight;
    public bool Bottom;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto tío, es mucho mas mejor así, porque tiene menos código.

Comment: @DanielRuiz si te sirvio la respuesta Asier no dudes en marcarla como respuesta aceptada con el boton en forma de V del lado izquiero, asi otros usuarios con tu mismo problema encontraran la solución mas rapido y tu generas reputación en el sitio

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el evento KeyPress o KeyDown de Form1, luego dentro haces que detecte la KeyCode, ejemplo:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
  If (e.KeyCode = "Codigo del número que sea"){
    //Activar los labels que necesites..
  }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo esto, así al pulsar una tecla entre 0 y 9 se pulsará el botón con el numero correspondiente al número pulsado entre :

```
button1, button2, button3, button4, .. button10.


     private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) > 48 && Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) < 59) 
           {
           char c1 = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar)+1);
           ((Button)this.Controls["button"+c1]).PerformClick();
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear **HotKeys** para esos casos (o para otras combinaciones).

La forma más usada para ello es así:

Primero pones el keyPreview del Form a true

```
myForm.KeyPreview = true;
```

Creas un handler para el evento KeyDown:

```
myForm.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form_KeyDown);
```

Un ejemplo del Handle podría ser este:

```
   // Hot keys handler
    void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)       // Ctrl-S Save
        {
            // Pon aquí lo que quieras hacer
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  //Evita que otros controles reciban el evento.
        }
    }
```

En lugar del  `if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)` en tu caso deberías poner algo del estilo  `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.0)`